# Moto G4 still on security level July 2016

Tags: updates, motorola-moto-g

I have bought an Moto G4 smartphone about half a year ago. At first system updates where available but now no more. The security level is still at July 2016 with Android version 6.0.1

The [Motorola Upgrade News](https://motorola-global-portal-de.custhelp.com/app/software-upgrade-news/g_id/1979/) site does not even list the G4 model.

How to get security updates for my phone?

Comment: [Come](https://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-g4) and dive into the world of tinkering and flashing. Official OTAs and firmwares get you newer versions that might not void your warranty; custom ROMs guarantee that you're always on the bleeding edge.

Comment: @AndyYan I know about custom roms but I hoped to avoid flashing my mobile phone

Comment: Then see if there's a stock ROM that fits your particular SKU, prefereably in OTA format, so that you can update without even losing your data.